# Handler wildcard mapping in web.config IIS 8

Tags: wildcard, iis-8, httphandler

I wanted to redirect to two different locations for same extension based on the root. Here is the example of my requirement.

/News/******/******.xyz

/Review/******/******.xyz

Here is a sample how we used to add handler, for redirecting checking only by extension.

```
<add name="MyHandler" path="*.xyz" verb="*" type="XYZHandle.xyzHandler" resourceType="Unspecified" requireAccess="Script" preCondition="integratedMode" />
```

So for redirecting to two different classes based on root as well as extension, how can I achieve?

Thanks in advance.